# Unable to send email attachement from Oozie Hue Browser on 4.1.0-cdh5.5.1

Tags: oozie, cloudera-cdh, hue

I am trying to send an email attachment from   Hue browser on CDH 5.5 I am getting error for not recognizing attachment tag.  I know OOZIE-2160 has fixed this issue on CDH5.5.  Error re-running workflow 0000006-160921134749647-oozie-oozi-W.E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'attachment'. No child element is expected at this.  I also tried running the job outside Hue still get the same error:
Oozie client build version: 4.1.0-cdh5.5.1

```
<action name="email-b5ff">
<email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
<to>test@abc.com</to>
<subject>attachment email</subject>
<body>Email is available</body>
<attachment>[hdfs://xxx:8020/user/eng//mergeConsolidatedReport.text]</attachment>
</email>
<ok to="End"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure those square brackets should be there?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Rhymoid. I removed bracket still got the same error.  Example says<body>[BODY]</body>
        <content_type>[CONTENT-TYPE]</content_type> 
        **<attachment>[COMMA-SEPARATED-HDFS-FILE-PATHS]</attachment>**

Comment: Anything I add I after body tag I am getting error Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'content_type'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: I think I got it. As indicated in the examples, you need to specify the updated `xmlns`: `<email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">`. It's subtle, but it matters a lot.

Comment: Thanks you so much.  Version was the issue.  Thanks again a lot Rhymoid!!

Answer (score 0):

From Rhymoid:
This fixed the issue.
I think I got it. As indicated in the examples, you need to specify the updated `xmlns: <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">`. It's subtle, but it matters a lot. – Rhymoid 20 hours ago

Comment: You can copy-paste the information from the comment and give users reference. Because visiting users have less tendency to read comments and also it will be available easily.